# jQuery - Wrap elements after one div and before anotherone

Tags: jquery, html

I have this html

```
<div class="sbox">
<div class="top-sbox"></div>
<h3>Menu</h3>
    <ul class="subpages">
    <li><a href="#">Subpagina</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Subpagina</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Subpagina</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Subpagina</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Subpagina</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="last">Subpagina</a></li>
    </ul>


<div class="bottom-sbox"></div>
</div>
```

How can I wrap all elements after div.top-sbox and before div.bottom-sbox.
Thank you!

I want this result:

```
<div class="sbox">
<div class="top-sbox"></div>
<div id="wrapper">
<h3>Menu</h3>
    <ul class="subpages">
    <li><a href="#">Subpagina</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Subpagina</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Subpagina</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Subpagina</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Subpagina</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="last">Subpagina</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>  
<div class="bottom-sbox"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: wrap them in what? how eaxactly do you mean? cus there are a tonne of ways to do this =D

Comment: wrap-it into a div, or any element. I edited my question!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here you are.

Edit: sorry. Even simpler: http://jsfiddle.net/ajRd2/1/

```
$('.top-sbox').nextUntil('.bottom-sbox').wrapAll('<div class="dwrap" />');
```

Comment: +1 The `nextUntil` was a nice enhancement fom jQuery 1.4. Good answer.

Comment: Thank you! I did not knew about .nextUntil, cool! I also added this: $('.top-sbox').each(function() to work smooth for more div's!

Answer (score -7):

Try a simple:
`$('.top-sbox').after('<div>');
$('.bottom-sbox').after('</div>');`

yep, much nicer answer above, use that one =)

Comment: Its nicer if you can inject a div into the dom rather than adding text to the markup twice.